# Create session before access to page

Tags: php, session

So when the user hits log in this code is executed: **LoggedIn.php**

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';
if ( !isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']) ) {
    // Could not get the data that should have been sent.
    die ('Username and/or password does not exist!');
}
// Prepare our SQL 
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = ?')) {
    // Bind parameters (s = string, i = int, b = blob, etc), hash the password using the PHP password_hash function.
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['username']);
    if(!$stmt->execute()){
    trigger_error("there was an error....".$mysqli->error, E_USER_WARNING);
    } 
    $stmt->store_result(); 
    // Store the result so we can check if the account exists in the database.
    if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
        $stmt->bind_result($password);
        $stmt->fetch();      
        // Account exists, now we verify the password.
        if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $password)) {
            // Verification success! User has loggedin!
            header('location: userPage.php');
                    //**should I create the session here?**

        } else {
            echo 'Incorrect username and/or password!';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Incorrect username blar password!';
    }
    $stmt->close();
} else {
    echo 'Could not prepare statement!';
}
?>
```

**OR** should the session be created when they are on the **userPage.php**. *This is the page that they get access to when they log on*

```
<?php
ob_start();
include 'connect.php';
if(!isset($_SESSION['username']) || !isset($_SESSION['password']))
{
    header("location:http://www.fortunefilly.com/loginTemplate.php");
}
else
{
    session_start();
    $username =$_SESSION['username']  ;
}
?>
```

But I don't think its actually creating a session because I try to echo out **$username** but It doesn't work. Just a few pointers on the scenario would be helpful

**Thank you in advance**

Comment: missing `session_start();` in the start of the code, without which all of this (related to sessions) is useless.

Comment: You need to assign the $_SESSION['username'] variable for it to have a value

Comment: you don't see anything in $_SESSION['username'] because you aren't assigning it after the session starts.  you're starting the session (session_start())  and then immediately trying to access $_SESSION['username'].

Comment: **DO NOT DO THIS** `$_SESSION['password']` - *Scary*.

Comment: *Geez Ralph!!!* Why would someone do that @Fred-ii-?

Comment: *Some like to live dangerously Sam* - @JayBlanchard

Comment: I'd rather not live dangerously I want my code to be secure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you plan to use/create/unset (whatsoever) the sessions, you must write `session_start();` in the very beginning of your code:

LoggedIn.php

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';
session_start();
if ( !isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']) ) {
    // Could not get the data that should have been sent.
    die ('Username and/or password does not exist!');
```

Or in your userPage.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
ob_start();
include 'connect.php';
if(!isset($_SESSION['username']) || !isset($_SESSION['password']))
{
    header("location:http://www.fortunefilly.com/loginTemplate.php");
}
```

**EDIT:**

Coming back to the problem now, you need to `set` the sessions, a good palce would be:

```
 if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $password)) {
            // Verification success! User has loggedin!

            header('location: userPage.php');
                    //**should I create the session here?**
```

*Taking it right out like a sore tooth*:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){ //should do it
```

Comment: This `|| !isset($_SESSION['password'])` should be stricken everywhere! *Scary*

Comment: @Fred-ii- I can't believe I missed that, well as they say _Time is the best teacher!_ ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- What should I have instead of || !isset($_SESSION['password'])

Comment: @SmallLegend Nothing, just take it right out *like a sore tooth*. Check to see if the session array is set/not empty for the username. Or you could add a condition to your `WHERE` clause and adding to it using both an id and username, just so there isn't a duplicate username, should that be the case. Make sure your table contains at least one UNIQUE column, or PK.

Comment: @SmallLegend well there you go, you're all set ;-) Remember to use a logout method and destroy the session.

Comment: how do I set the session?  something like $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username']?

Comment: *You got it Pontiac* ^ @SmallLegend

Comment: @Fred-ii- He should rather be Big Legend, no? ;)

Comment: I'm getting Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home4/fortunefilly/public_html/userPage.php:3) in /home4/fortunefilly/public_html/userPage.php on line 9 now

Comment: @HawasKaPujaari *Big surprises do often come in "Small" packages* ;-)

Comment: @SmallLegend See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php

Comment: This error keeps popping up, before I had this problem ha

Comment: @SmallLegend check the link provided above, it has _EVERYTHING_ you need ;)

Comment: Bloody too much is what it is haha

Comment: @SmallLegend don't let me down man, I just called you a Big Legend :P

Comment: @HawasKaPujaari haha thanks for your help man, got to trawl through this 5000 word essay to depict my problem wish me luck

Comment: @SmallLegend best wishes and prayers with you soldier! go get em' and remember we got your back ;)

Comment: Can't understand why theres an error with the  session_start @HawasKaPujaari on the **userPage**

Answer (score 1):

session must be started before accessing session variables:

```
<?php
session_start();
ob_start();
include 'connect.php';
if(!isset($_SESSION['username']) || !isset($_SESSION['password']))
{
    header("location:http://www.fortunefilly.com/loginTemplate.php");
}
else
{
    $username =$_SESSION['username']  ;
}
```

?>

Comment: this still doesn't assign $_SESSION['username'].  That needs to be assigned before it will have a value.

Comment: Where do I assign it?

Comment: Of course, but you wouldn't be checking username for isset if you didn't think the value was set elsewhere either. The scenario shown suggests it's set elsewhere, such as the validation of login page.

Comment: same applies here (strike it) `|| !isset($_SESSION['password'])` - Ever heard of session hijacking?

Comment: that aimed at *moi?* ^ @William_Wilson

Comment: Haha, no. Doing to many things at once. I've merged around 4 trains of thought... and it splashed over onto this thread.

Comment: @William_Wilson No problemo ;-) was just pointing out about sessions hijacking. Every little bit helps ;-)

Comment: *goes back to the pavilion*